# git push heroku masterHow do I Migrate Django App on Heroku from git deploy to container deploy?

Tags: python, django, docker, heroku

Now that Heroku supports deploying an app straight from you docker image.

I would like to migrate my existing Django app, Which is already running on heroku (using the standard deploy methodology: `git push heroku master`) to a Container based app (see [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime), but without loosing all the configuration already done (postgreSQL, mainly).

The documentation linked above shows how to start from scratch but not how to migrate in cases you already have an app setup the old fashioned way.

Is there a easy way to migrate git app to a container app?

I have searched  a lot and couldn't find any tutorial that did not assume that you where creating a new app from scratch. Can it be done?

Comment: Why do you think you would lose anything? Postgres is an external service anyway.

Comment: On the git deploy the IP of the database is defined by an environment variable in the productions environment. May this will require some manual configuration on the container....

Comment: But according to the docs environment variables should work in exactly the same way with a docker image. Again, why do you think you need to do anything different?

Comment: For starters the example dockerfiles available so far, are too simple. I am working on my own. When I get it to work, I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0):

you can find document [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/09/how-to-deploy-django-applications-on-heroku.html)

you can also find video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kvTsCskJA0&t=392s)

Comment: This is what I already have. What I want to do is: getting from having a app fully deployed by Git push to an app encapsulated in a acontainer.